# mysql insert into query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The query is pasted below. Basically I have a users table, and I want to create 1 record for every entry in the users table in the controls table. I need the user_id from the users table when I'm inserting into the controls table. I get a syntax error when I try and run the query below. I've looked at a bunch of other MySQL examples that do something similar but get the same error. I'm running MySQL 5.6.21.

This will end up being a Rails migration, so I am also amenable to using ActiveRecord, but haven't really figure out how to do something like this with it.

```
INSERT into controls (default, whitelist, user_id, admin_status, system_status, created_at, updated_at) values (0, 0, (SELECT id FROM users), 'inactive', 'sleeping', DATE(NOW), DATE(NOW));
```

Comment: DEFAULT is a reserved word in MySQL. The error message would have been a clue. Also, you can't use SELECT that way. See INSERT... SELECT syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you're trying to mix a `SELECT` with `VALUES` (which is used for inputting literal values).

Try:

```
INSERT into controls
    (`default`, whitelist, user_id, admin_status, system_status, created_at, updated_at)
    SELECT 0, 0, id, 'inactive', 'sleeping', NOW(), NOW() FROM users;
```

Answer (score 1):

`DEFAULT` is a MySQL reserved word. You may need to enclose that column name in backticks.

```
INSERT into controls (`default`, whitelist, 
                      ^       ^
```

Those are **backtick** characters (key to the left of the **<kbd>1/!</kbd>** key), not single quotes.

The error message from MySQL should indicate where in the SQL text MySQL thinks the problem is.

If this is a new table, strongly consider using a column name that is *not* a MySQL reserved word.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

---

The `SELECT` in the context of the VALUES clause needs to return at most *one* row. You'd need to ensure that SELECT doesn't return more than one row, e.g. add a LIMIT 1 clause. But

Reading your question again... if you want to insert a row in the new `controls`  table for every row that's in users table, don't use the VALUES keyword. Use the `INSERT ... SELECT` form of the INSERT statement.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html